# What are Tier-1 and Tier-2 programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I was reading [this redmonk programming language ranking](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2013/07/25/language-rankings-6-13/) article. There is mentioned about  Tier-1 and Tier-2 languages.

[image: Programming Language Ranking]

So, I know what are Tier-1 languages.

Also, in one of the [similar article](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2012/02/08/language-rankings-2-2012/), it was said that

> *Scala may be separating itself from the other Tier 2 languages*

My question is,

How are programming languages categorized as "Tier 1" or "Tier 2" languages?

What are the differences between these different tiers of programming languages?

Comment: That's not "a thing" I'm generally aware of. It seems to be a classification the author of those articles has come up with purely on a whim.

Comment: The link provided in the page is to a site that explains the methodology; search for “Popularity is tiered”.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a "code" problem and may be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclosure**: I produced the charts referenced, and all of the mentioned caveats apply.

As other answers have noted, the Tiers are essentially language groupings - they have no formal or technical definition otherwise. When Drew Conway and John Myles White first performed the analysis back in 2010, they noticed that plots of the correlated and ranked languages produced visible clusters of languages. The first two tend to be very distinct, the tier or tiers after much less so.

The tiers are mentioned in the above piece simply because they appear to roughly correspond to observed language usage, and are therefore more reliable than the actual numerical ranking, which must be taken with a grain of salt.

If you want to identify the tiers, then, simply view the full size chart and note the placement of languages within the clustered groupings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be based on popularity and "future use"

From the article you mention:

`No claims are made here that these rankings are representative of general usage more broadly. They are nothing more or less than an examination of the correlation between two populations we believe to be predictive of future use, hence their value.`

Read more: http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2013/07/25/language-rankings-6-13/#ixzz2aSMqTjj5

Answer (score 0):

It is just the community rank for the popularity of the languages.

Answer (score 0):

These tiers are based upon their total use and popularity. Tier 1 languages are multiuse and widely used. Tier 2 languages are used to a lesser extent, usually based on the limits to their intended uses. At least that is how I understand it.

Answer (score -2):

> How are programming languages categorized as "Tier 1" or "Tier 2"
>   languages?

Only because of their popularity, I guess. Not placing Assembly in first tier is somewhat odd.

Comment: That's it? Also in that regards, Visual Basic should also be in Tier-1 language, is it not?